# cakephp get all dropdown options from DB

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a drop-down and drop-down options in separate tables. That's good but now I want to be able to retrieve all the options with the drop-down code. On this page I have all of the drop-downs and items. Let's say the drop-down code is `dropdown1`.

I'd like to be able to do

```
$this->Form->input('dropdownitem_id', array('options' => $dropdown['dropdown1']));
```

Is there a way to do this without a helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom helper to get the exact behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

1) why do you want to do it "without a helper"?

2) Yes, use normal PHP stuff - ie foreach() loop that echos HTML content to the page

Just look at what content the helper generates, and use PHP to mimic it.

```
<select name="whatever">
    <?php
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo '<option value=" . $item['id'] . '">' . $item['name'] . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

(something like that - I wrote that quickly off the top of my head, but you should get the idea)

Answer (score 2):

In the controller,

```
$dropdownitems = $this->OtherModel->find('list');
$this->set(compact('dropdownitems'));
```

In your view

```
$this->Form->input('dropdownitem_id');
```

The options for select will be populated automatically.

But I don't understand, what you meant by helper ?

Comment: `$this->Form->input...` uses the "FormHelper" to write an input field(s) and therefore is not an answer to the question.

Comment: why would you want to do it without helper ?

Comment: Exactly what I asked: `1) why do you want to do it "without a helper"?`

Comment: I meant custom helper. My form input dropdown is populated with all dropdown options which is not what I want. I want to be able to filter the list by dropdown_id but for that I have to use find("all") which doesn't return a list of options.

Answer (score 0):

You should use containable behavior.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Then you would query the top level element.

After you have done so.

You must run a foreach loop still as Dave said and format the option.

Let me know if you need help with the containable, they are a life saver and your friend !

Comment: In ~90% of my pages that use a dropdown like mentioned, the dropdown is to associate the main item with a selection of other items.  In those cases, you can't really use Containable, since it's not yet related, but instead, a complete option of all things that are available to associate.